# A comprehensive list of binomial identities?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Is there a comprehensive resource listing binomial identities? I am more interested in combinatorial proofs of such identities, but even a list without proofs will do.

Comment: You've seen http://dlmf.nist.gov/26.3 and http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Binomial/ and Gradshteyn and Ryzhik and probably even the Graham-Knuth-Patashnik book I suppose?

Comment: I am aware of Concrete Math book, but I don't have it now, hence I was looking for some online resource. I think the wolfram link you just gave is quite a good one. Thanks.

Comment: Detailing the info above you find in section 0.15 of Gradshteyn, Ryzhik, Jeffrey, Zwillinger's *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products* http://www.amazon.com/Table-Integrals-Products-Sixth-Gradshteyn/dp/0122947576/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1282562268&sr=1-1#_ a list of 36 Sums of the binomial coefficients, without proof, but with a reference for it.

Comment: The pedant in me would like to add that no list will be "comprehensive" as one can generate an infinite number of binomial identities... That being said +1, I think this is a useful question.

Comment: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~jverstra/bijections.pdf is a link with more than a few combinatorial identities - with proofs.

Answer (score 49):

The most comprehensive list I know of is H.W. Gould's *Combinatorial Identities.*  It is available directly from him if you contact him.  He also has some pdf documents available for download from his [web site](https://web.archive.org/web/20190629193344/http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/).  Although he says they do "NOT replace [*Combinatorial Identities*] which remains in print with supplements," they still contain many more binomial identities even than in *Concrete Mathematics*.  In general, Gould's work is a great resource for this sort of thing; he has spent much of his career collecting and proving combinatorial identities.

*Added*: Another useful reference is John Riordan's *Combinatorial Identities*.  It's hard to pick one of its 250 pages at random and *not* find at least one binomial coefficient identity there.  Unfortunately, the identities are not always organized in a way that makes it easy to find what you are looking for.  Still it's a good resource.

Answer (score 18):

If you do possess Concrete Mathematics, check out `5.1 Basic Identities` and `5.2 Basic Practice`. The list can be found at P174 `Table 174 The top ten binomial coefficient identities`.