# Comprehensive collection of combinatorial identities - with proofs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I read the answers to [A comprehensive list of binomial identities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3085/a-comprehensive-list-of-binomial-identities), and although there are links to listings of combinatorial identities *without* proofs, I am looking for such resources which **have proofs** accompanying each identity.  I haven't found this yet on the web, so a textbook suggestion would also help.

Comment: the alternative for me has been to ask a question here at   http://math.stackexchange.com for help with the proof.

Comment: I'm not sure whether Gould has proofs, or just lists: http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/

Comment: The book, $A=B$, gives you the tools to prove just about any combinatorial identity you want to yourself. http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html

Comment: @GerryMyerson Very nice!