# Collection of less well-known, non-trivial, elegant story proofs (ie, "double counting proofs") of combinatorial identities

Tags: combinatorics, big-list, combinatorial-proofs

By story proof I mean **proving a combinatorial identity by counting the number of elements of some carefully chosen set in two different ways to obtain the different expressions in the identity**. The following is my favorite:

> Prove (try the algebraic method!) $$\sum _ { k = 0 } ^ { n } {n \choose k} 2 ^ { k } { {n - k }\choose { \left[ \frac { n - k } { 2 } \right]} } = { {2 n + 1 } \choose { n }},$$
>
> Proof: Assume there are $2n+1$ people, where one of them T is single (it's me), the rest of them are $n$ pairs of lovers $(a_n,b_n)$. Now we need to choose $n$ among the $2n+1$ people for a dance party. There are $2$ methods:
>
> A. Choose $n$ people arbitrarily, which accounts for ${ {2 n + 1 } \choose { n }}$ combinations in total.
>
> B. Fix $k$, where $0\leq k \leq n $. Choose $k$ pairs of lovers, and demand only one of them can go to the party, which accounts for ${n \choose k} 2 ^ { k }$ combinations. Choose ${ \left[ \frac { n - k } { 2 } \right] }$ from the remaining $n-k$ pairs, and the two of them don't need to be separated.
>
> If $n-k$ is odd, 
>   $$ k + 2 \left[ \frac { n - k } { 2 } \right] = n - 1,$$ T can also join the party!
>
> If $n-k$ is even, $$ k + 2 \left[ \frac { n - k } { 2 } \right] = n,$$ T cannot join the party :(
>
> When $k$ is fixed, the total number of combinations of the $n$ people is ${ {n - k }\choose { \left[ \frac { n - k } { 2 } \right]} }$. Let $k$ vary from $0$ to $n$, then method B produces $\sum _ { k = 0 } ^ { n } {n \choose k} 2 ^ { k } { {n - k }\choose { \left[ \frac { n - k } { 2 } \right]} }$ combinations.
>
> As the 2 methods should result in the same number of combinations, the identity is proved.
>
> Source: My variant of Gu Jian's proof from Collection of CMO (Chinese Mathematics Olympiad) Problems (Sorry for can't provide a picture as it's written in Chinese).

I would like to collect everyone's favorite story proof. Apologize if this is a duplicate.

Blue's link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)

Any other less well-known ones?

Comment: Can you ad a source of your problem?

Comment: @greedoid done!

Comment: you might wanna checkout this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3085/a-comprehensive-list-of-binomial-identities

Comment: @pointguard0 Thanks for the reference! Though I'm more interested in the proof per se.

Comment: There are a few examples in [Wikipedia's "Double Counting" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)).

Comment: @Blue Thanks! Though I'm greedy.