# Inequality between binomial sums

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

I want to prove that the following inequality holds whenever $k\leq n-1$ and $1\leq i\leq \lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor$.

> $$\frac{2}{C}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{i+1} \leq \frac{k}{i}\sum_{j=i}^{k-1}
>  (k-j)\binom{j-1}{i-1}\binom{n-k+j-1}{j}$$

where $C = \max(k,n-k)+1$.

Two identities I suspect might be very useful here are
$$\binom{k}{i+1} = \sum_{j=i}^{k-1} (k-j)\binom{j-1}{i-1}$$
$$\binom{n-1}{k-1}=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{n-k+j-1}{j}$$

I tried to use these and the Chebyshev's inequality (which states that if $a_1\leq \cdots \leq a_n$ and $b_1\leq \cdots \leq b_n$, then $\sum a_i \cdot \sum b_i \leq n \sum a_ib_i$) but it didn't work. I think that this inequality is somehow "tight".

Also, I tried splitting into two cases $k\leq n-k$ and $k\geq n-k$ to have a more concrete expression for $C$. Any help would be highly appreciated.

EDIT: I have tried approaching the case $i=1$, and many identities can be used. The inequality in this case is very tight, and I think that proceeding via induction on $i$ does not help, as the inequality seems to get tighter at every step.

EDIT2: The problem with the Chebyshev approach is that the sequence $(k-j)\binom{j-1}{i-1}$ is not increasing (hence it is not possible to use the Chebyshev's inequality as stated).

EDIT3: I have noticed using Zeilberger's algorithm that
$$\sum_{j=i}^{k-1} j\binom{j-1}{i-1}\binom{n-k+j-1}{j} = \frac{i(i+1)(n-k)}{n(n+i-k)} \binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{i+1}$$

However, no closed expression seems to exist for

$$\sum_{j=i}^{k-1}\binom{j-1}{i-1}\binom{n-k+j-1}{j}$$

Comment: This inequality does not seem to hold when $k=n$ because then the right-hand side is zero,  isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it has to be $1\leq k\leq n-1$. I'll edit that now.

Comment: I think that for $i=2,k=4$ and $n=5$, the inequality does not hold because the left-hand side is $10$ and the right-hand side is $8$.

Comment: It doesn't hold either when $k=2$ for $n= 3$ , $n=4$ nor $n=5$

Comment: It seems that $i \ge 3$ and $k \le n-2$  is required.

Comment: I made a subtle typo when I wrote $C$, I sincerely apologize..

Comment: It is however true that putting the "old $C$" (without the $+1$) the inequality seems to hold for $i\geq 3$ and $k\leq n-2$. Proving that case would be useful too.

Comment: Did you check the list of binomial identities such as Gould's Combinatorial Identities, see more: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3085/a-comprehensive-list-of-binomial-identities

Comment: I've seen quite a few edits : is the current version completely right? I mean, I'd like to try this question when possible.

Comment: Yes. The version now is entirely correct. However, if you change slightly one of the parameters and prove something “tighter” for all but a few exceptional values, it can be useful too. For example as the modification discussed in the comments above.

Comment: @River I have used Maxima to get simpler expressions and I couldn’t find anything. I honestly doubt that a simple expression could exist and not been found by these algorithms.

Comment: Do you care about $+1$ in the definition of $C$ or $+1000$ will be equally useful?

Comment: @fedja Was wondering about the same thing, it seems to me that the inequality will hold for some $C$, possibly explicitly derivable, which is similar but not equal to that given.

Comment: @fedja I care about the +1, but if you manage to prove it for all but a finite number of values of n assuming that there is a +1000, it would be useful too.

Comment: The left-hand side is a multinomial times a fraction (without factorials). The right hand side is the sum over a multinomial times a similar fraction. What you have looks similar to the hockey stick identity for multinomials (https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/34-3/jones.pdf). To make it exactly fit the identity, you'd have to add a second summation, but perhaps you can bound that summation by the first. Perhaps the fractions can also bounded by your 2/C. Anyway, that's a sketch of a potential way to do it using the hockey stick identity for multinomials.

Answer (score 2):

(Still a work in progress, see last expression for a sufficient condition on $C$.)

The strategy is to rewrite both sides as multinomials. We then get something that looks similar enough to the hockey stick identity for multinomials.

For the left hand side:

$$\frac{2}{C}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{i+1} = \frac{2}{C}\binom{n}{n-k,\,i+1,\,k-i-1}$$

For the right hand side:

$$\frac{k}{i}(k-j)\binom{j-1}{i-1}\binom{n-k+j-1}{j}$$

$$= \binom{n-k+j}{n-k,\, i, \, j-i} \frac{k(k-j)(n-k)}{j(n-k+j)}$$

The hockey stick identity for multinomials (https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/34-3/jones.pdf) says that:

$$\binom{n}{n-k,\,i+1,\,k-i-1}$$

$$= \sum_{j=i}^{k-1} \binom{n-k+j}{n-k-1,\, i+1, \, j-i} + \sum_{j=i}^{k-1} \binom{n-k+j}{n-k,\, i, \, j-i}$$

$$= \frac{n-k + i +1}{i+1} \sum_{j=i}^{k-1} \binom{n-k+j}{n-k,\, i, \, j-i}$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{2}{C}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{i+1} = \frac{2}{C} \cdot \frac{n-k + i +1}{i+1} \sum_{j=i}^{k-1} \binom{n-k+j}{n-k,\, i, \, j-i}$$

We are done if we can show for all valid $j$ that:

$$\frac{2}{C} \cdot \frac{n-k + i +1}{i+1} \leq \frac{k(k-j)(n-k)}{j(n-k+j)}$$

Or that:

$$\frac{2j(n-k + i +1)(n-k+j)}{k(i+1)(k-j)(n-k)} \leq C$$

Since the left hand side increases in $j$, we can plug in $j=k-1$:

$$\frac{2(k-1)(n-k + i +1)(n-1)}{k(i+1)(n-k)} \leq C$$

We could get tighter bounds by not trying to prove the coefficient is larger for all $j$ but just enough of them (specifically when the multinomial is large). Also, when $k$ is almost $n$, the summation is very flat, and so we don't care as much about $j=k-1$ versus $j=k-2$, etc. So, if $k$ is close to $n$, then the inequality might only need to hold for a somewhat smaller value of $j$. I think, we might need to break up the proof into cases over $k$. (The $k-j$ term in the denominator then becomes pretty important.)

Comment: Regarding to your last sentence, I do have direct proofs for $i=1$, but I agree that it is exactly the scenario in which the right-hand-side and the left-hand-side have minimum difference when fixing $k$ and $n$.

Comment: @LuisFerroni Interesting, $i=1$ seems to be the most difficult case for me to prove. Maybe your proof for $i=1$ could be generalized? Are you able to post it?

Comment: If I find time to write it up, I will post it. (Notice that when $i=1$, the right hand side admits a closed form which allows you to work much more comfortably)

Comment: I have checked some extreme values (n=400 and 40, k=20, i=1), and what you say holds up nice and tightly.

Comment: @LuisFerroni I made a mistake with the hockey stick identity (fixed) and simplified some things.